# Wrong intensity of colors from seaborn

Tags: python, plot, colors, seaborn

I´m working with some plots on seaborn and getting the wrong colors, E.G.

For this plot intead of red, I´m getting a pink plot:

```
sns.distplot(df.X.sample(10), bins=25, norm_hist=False,kde=False,color="Red")
```

[image]

This in the only configuration I made:

```
sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
```

Comment: You are getting red, but its opacity isn't 100%.

Comment: @asongtoruin Yes, you're right. So you will need `color="Red", hist_kws=dict(alpha=1)` to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `distplot` [sets the alpha of the histograms to be 0.4](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/f0349b1a7f1e022cb1da8b94f2e019f04eeed397/seaborn/distributions.py#L216). To get your opaque histogram, you could instead do

```
sns.distplot(df.X.sample(10), bins=25, norm_hist=False,kde=False,color="Red",hist_kws={'alpha': 1})
```